# run time error 13 VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm a beginner in vba and I'm trieing to run a code . I simply get run time error 13 - type mismatch'

The code is the following:

```
Sub Range_Copy_Examples()
Worksheets("Luni").Range("A1:A800").Value = Worksheets("Rout").Range("A1:A800").Value
Worksheets("Luni").Range("B1:B800").Value = Worksheets("Rout").Range("B1:B800").Value
Worksheets("Luni").Range("C1:C800").Value = Worksheets("Rout").Range("C1:C800").Value
Worksheets("Luni").Range("D1:D800").Value = Worksheets("Rout").Range("D1:D800").Value
Worksheets("Luni").Range("E1:E800").Value = Worksheets("Rout").Range("E1:E800").Value
Worksheets("Luni").Range("F1:F800").Value = Worksheets("Rout").Range("F1:F800").Value
Worksheets("Luni").Range("G1:G800").Value = Worksheets("Rout").Range("G1:G800").Value
Worksheets("Luni").Range("H1:H800").Value = Worksheets("Rout").Range("H1:H800").Value
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Rout").Range("A1:A800").Copy
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Luni").Range("A1:A800").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Rout").Range("B1:B800").Copy
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Luni").Range("B1:B800").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Rout").Range("C1:C800").Copy
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Luni").Range("C1:C800").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Rout").Range("D1:D800").Copy
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Luni").Range("D1:D800").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Rout").Range("E1:E800").Copy
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Luni").Range("E1:E800").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Rout").Range("F1:F800").Copy
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Luni").Range("F1:F800").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Rout").Range("G1:G800").Copy
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Luni").Range("G1:G800").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Rout").Range("H1:H800").Copy
Workbooks("Plan livrari 2018 Landscape - final.xlsm").Worksheets("Luni").Range("H1:H800").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End sub

   If Target = Range("F4") Then
        If ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Value <> "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox2").Visible = True
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox2").Visible = False
        End If
    End If

    If Target = Range("F5") Then
        If ActiveSheet.Range("F5").Value <> "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox2").Visible = True
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox2").Visible = False
        End If
    End If

      If Target = Range("F6") Then
        If ActiveSheet.Range("F6").Value <> "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox3").Visible = True
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox3").Visible = False
        End If
End sub
```

I'm getting run time error 13 - type mismatch and debug hilight thr following:

```
If Target = Range("F4") Then
```

Comment: please try to debug your code and investigate more information of the error, we can't do it for you. Once you share more information (at least which exact line gives the error, what is the value of relevant variables, what should happen instead..) we might help you.

Comment: also `If Target = Range("F4") Then` is out of any `sub` which is not allowed in VBA, `Target` doesn't seem to have a value. Coding is not just putting code snippets together ... :(

Comment: It's possible the solution is as simple as the first `End Sub` should not be there.  Either that, or your code example is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

`Target` isn't declared anywhere in your posted code (it might be a globally declared variable), and you probably do not have `Option Explicit` enabled. Enabling `Option Explicit` is a good idea generally and it will throw errors for undeclared variables before running.

The error is because `Range()` returns a Range object, and `Target` is probably not an `Object` nor `Range` data type.

You probably pasted this from an example that declared `Target` as an argument in the `Sub` declaration.

If none of this makes any sense, you will need to do some reading.

Comment: What you wrote is true, but probably won't be enough for the OP to solve the problem. The solution would be to learn programming.

Comment: I don't think that's justification for downvoting.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: That is the sole intent behind my last sentence, so we agree.